# MUI Data Grid aggregation function resulting in concatenated currency strings instead of summing values - how to fix?

Tags: reactjs, mui-x

I was given a task to display data in MUI data grid table. The grid should support row grouping and aggregated columns by summing up all values in a column. I was able to add the row grouping and aggregation of columns but the issue I'm facing is that I have data with value that has currency symbol attached to it which makes it a string and the autosum is concatenating it instead of summing up value because it's a string. The result looks like this $530$400 instead of $930. How can I override the autosum function to perform the calculation myself and display the result accordingly

Example on codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-frost-dz8jns

```
`<iframe src="https://codesandbox.io/embed/bold-frost-dz8jns?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark"
     style="width:100%; height:500px; border:0; border-radius: 4px; overflow:hidden;"
     title="bold-frost-dz8jns"
     allow="accelerometer; ambient-light-sensor; camera; encrypted-media; geolocation; gyroscope; hid; microphone; midi; payment; usb; vr; xr-spatial-tracking"
     sandbox="allow-forms allow-modals allow-popups allow-presentation allow-same-origin allow-scripts"
   ></iframe>`
```

import * as React from "react";
import {
DataGridPremium,
} from "@mui/x-data-grid-premium";

const rows = [
{

```
ProductCategoryName: "",
ProductName: "Magnum Brownie 80ml",
UnitPrice: '$2160',
UnitsNeeded: 1,
hierarchy: ["cat1", "Magnum Brownie 80ml"]
```

},
{
ProductCategoryName: "",
ProductName: "Magnum Brownie 80ml",
UnitPrice: '$2160',
UnitsNeeded: 1,
hierarchy: ["cat2", "Magnum Brownie 80ml"]
},
{
ProductCategoryName: "",
ProductName: "Magnum Brownie",
UnitPrice: '$2160',
UnitsNeeded: 1,
hierarchy: ["cat2", "Magnum Brownie"]
}
];

const columns = [
{
field: "UnitsNeeded",
headerName: "QTY",
type: "number"
},
{
field: "UnitPrice",
headerName: "Price",
type: "number",
}
];

const getTreeDataPath = (row) => row.hierarchy;

const getRowId = (row) => row.hierarchy.join("/");

export default function AggregationTreeData() {
return (
<div style={{ height: 450, width: "100%" }}>
<DataGridPremium
treeData
rows={rows}
columns={columns}
getTreeDataPath={getTreeDataPath}
getRowId={getRowId}
groupingColDef={{ headerName: "Product Name", width: 250 }}
initialState={{
aggregation: {
model: {
UnitsNeeded: "sum",
UnitPrice: "sum"
}
}
}}
/>

);
}